# How to detect infinite dimensionality using Algebraic topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

It is well known that the common proof of invariance of domain (so dimension of a Manifold is a topological invariant).

I have heard that there is a theory of infinite dimensional manifolds, i.e topological spaces locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ or perhaps an even bigger space like $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$. Note that I don't know anything about the theory of infinite dimensional manifolds, just that they exist.

Now the classic proof of invariance of domain fails, because $S^\infty$ is contractible. So my question, is there any finer method, using tools from algebraic topology, where given a Manifold of arbitrary dimension, I can determine its dimension?

Thanks

Comment: Manifold has dimension baked into its definition. How can you even have a manifold without knowing its dimension?

Comment: @freakish I don't have a particular example in mind, but I am sure there could be problems of the form "Let M be a topological space locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^X$ for some set X. Furthermore suppose that smthsmthsmth, then show that $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose such questions can occur. So, first of all, unlike finite dimension, infinite dimensional spaces are not uniquely determined by dimension. So concrete choice of "$\mathbb{R}^X$", i.e. the underlying normed space is important, the choice of $X$ alone is not enough. I know there is some research on [Banach manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_manifold). I'm not sure about its algebraic topology, but note that no infinite dimensional manifold is locally compact.

Comment: Furthermore, some things trivialize in infinite dimension. For example every infinite dimensional smooth [Hilbert manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold) is an open subspace of some Hilbert space. A situation very different from finite dimension.

Comment: As for dimension itself, most of the encountered spaces will have $2^{\aleph_0}$ as its dimension. That is because countable dimensional spaces are not complete (which is often an important property), while higher dimensions rarely occur naturally. I deliberately ignored continuum hypothesis here, since such debate is even less important.

Comment: @freakish I see, I hadn't thought of the fact that there is "only one" interesting infinite dimension. Thanks

Comment: May be you are fishing for Q-manifolds: They are locally compact and have countably infinite dimension. They also have some interesting algebraic topological invariants. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://bookstore.ams.org/cbms-28&ved=2ahUKEwil1ZKDs6SCAxV2J0QIHXoIDiwQFnoECBMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw05ID45hc06m0lFIdiL3Bic

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'll go check that out, thanks a lot.